# Connecting TWO Android devices via USB OTG cable and running adb on the rooted one

Tags: android, usb, adb, root

I have two generic Chinese tablets, both JB 4.2.2; one rooted another not rooted and no pc available here.
I have an OTG USB cable that will plug one tablet into the other.
Both are nearly identical, although one has a newer build by a few days.
The cable works, the non-rooted one draws power from the other during the connection, and the cable has worked as a data cable.
I use TERMINAL on the rooted device.

> adb devices

lists no devices.
The non-rooted device is defined as a Large Storage Device, and the JB symbol appears to show a connection established, but I've also tried Camera AND MultiMedia Device, which don't cause the non-rooted device to be listed under 'adb devices' either.
BOTH are set to 'USB Debugging'.
The rooted one was initially not recognized by adb under Ubuntu 14.04 but this problem WAS fixed by adding the vendorId; 0x1f3a to adb on Ubuntu using;

> echo 0x1f3a >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

which allowed Ubuntu to recognize it. Does the version on Android also need to know the VendorId/ProductId that;

> lsusb

displays?

Is there something similar to the Ubuntu fix that I'm missing re. the Android version?